# How to prevent keyboard hiding when pressing and holding the UITextview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I am developing chat application, in the chatViewController i have a tableView and textfield at bottom of the view . Messages are showing using uiTextView.

Scenario -

while messaging, the keyboard is on, i want to copy the last message text so while pressing and holding the textview keyboard got dismissed.

I don't want to hide the keyboard while copying the text.

If anyone know the solution please help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the long press recognizer for copying text... so in long press recognizer method just add this line:

```
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: No I am used inbuilt feature , Enabled UserInteractionenabled

Comment: Use This method                                                                                      - (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (textView == self.editableTextView) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}